# How do you rotate a UIImageView with a UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uislider

If I want to rotate a `UIImageVIew` by using a `UISlider`, what would I put under the function `mySliderAction`? This doesn't seem to be doing anything...

```
@IBOutlet weak var ball: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var C: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var mySlider: UISlider!

@IBAction func mySliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let rotation = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi * -1, duration: TimeInterval(5.0))
    let infiniteRotation = SKAction.repeatForever(rotation)
    c.run(infiniteRotation)
}
```

Comment: Retrieve `sender.value`. Calculate some angle from it (but what's it's slider max value? min value? What's the angle max value? min value?). Perform the rotation with that angle.

Comment: @Larme   The min is 0 the max is 1000, and I'm not sure about angles but I would like it so when the slider is at 0 the angle is 0 and when going to 1000 it does a full rotation to the right.

Comment: Please only add _relevant_ code to your questions, e.g. there's no need for `override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}`

Comment: @AshleyMills Sorry about that, I will start doing that.

Answer (score 2):

A CGTransform function that uses as parameter the slider's progress parameter.

```
c.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: sliderProgress)
```

Please note that sliderProgress must of type CGFloat and is for Radians and not normal corner angles. So you gotta convert Slider's change param to CGFloat.

Then you have to consider the minValue of Slider to produce a rotation of 0 degrees and the maxValue a 360 degrees rotation(2 * pi in radians).

Ok. So select the slider in the story board and edit its settings like this:[image]

It's important to set the slider's minimum value, and value to 0 and the max value to 2 * pi value for a 360 rotation. That is 6,28318531. Hit enter and go to your `ViewController`.

Edit your rotate function like this:

```
@IBAction func rotateImage(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let pram = sender.value
    image.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(pram))
}
```

Please Note! When you are typing the maximum value of 6,28318531, make sure to use this kind of dot "," (like a comma), and not the traditional dot "." , otherwise xCode won't take the value.

Also should you need a 90 degrees turn then change the maxValue to pi/2, which is about 1.57079632679, and pi, which is 3.14159265359 for a 180 rotation.

Comment: How would I go about making sliderProgress a CGFloat? I have tried what you said, however I am new to coding so may not be understanding clearly.

Comment: I'll type the code in a minute. Please see answer's edit.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(slider.value * 2*M_PI / slider.maximumValue);
```

**Swift 5 version**

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(slider.value * 2 * M_PI / slider.maximumValue))
```

Here, `M_PI` holds the value of π.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others